# Disable next/prev partial view in center mode slick slider

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I want to use center mode in slick slider but need to avoid partial prev/next slides. (Just show the three main divs only)

My settings is like this,

```
$('.framefitFacelist').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: false,
  centerMode: true
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: set `centerMode` to `False`

Comment: But I want center mode, just disable prev/next partial views..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can change this with javascript. You have to set the `opacity` of the partial slides to `0`;

Essentially you can create a variable and set `prev` and `next` slide opacity to `0` when concatenating css and then call the `beforeChange` slick event.

I found this fiddle that seems to achieve what you are looking for.

test it out

https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/uwgjx6nv/